# Creating an HTML table in Java

Tags: java, html

I have a problem in my code when I am creating a table in Java using HTML. This is my code:

```
for(int station : stations){
   String rowcolor = null;
   String stationnum = Integer.toString(station);
   String lastDate = pollData(station); //CALL GET LAST 
   String status = determineStatus(station, lastDate); // CALL DETERMINE STATUS

    switch(status){
       case " ONLINE":
           rowcolor = (" <tr bgcolor=\"#5FFF33\">");
           break;
       case " OFFLINE":
           rowcolor = (" <tr bgcolor=\"red\">");
           break;
       case " DELAYED":
           rowcolor = (" <tr bgcolor=\"yellow\">");
           break;
   }

    out.write("<html>" +
       "<body>" +
       "<table border ='1'>" +
       "<tr>" +
       "<td>Station Number</td>" +
       "<td>Station Name</td>" +
       "<td>Status</td>" +
       "<td>As of Date</td>" +
       "</tr>");

    out.write(rowcolor + "<td>");
    out.write(stationnum);
    out.write("</td><td>");
    out.write(stationnname[id]);
    out.write("</td><td>");
    out.write(status);
    out.write("</td><td>");
    out.write(lastDate);
    out.write("</table>" +
       "</body>" +
       "</html>"); 
     id++; 
    out.close(); 
   }   

   }catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println(e);
   }
```

and this is the output:

[image]

When I remove the `out.close();` part, the output is this:

[image]

As you can see, the image there is a problem in creating the table. Something is not right but I can’t find a way to fix it. Please help me; thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the generated HTML as source. I think you'll quickly see the problem

Comment: i want to contine the table just like in image one but it stops. so when i remove the out.close(); part it will get all the stations but it displays it one by one...

Comment: Yes, I know what you want to do. Have you looked at the generated HTML source code yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Phil said,`out.close();` is inside the `for` loop,you need to change it to outside the `for` loop,due to if it's inside loop,`out` will close for the first iterate,and will not work for other records

```
for(int station : stations){

}
out.close();
```

Comment: It's not the only thing in the loop that shouldn't be there

Comment: @Phil,yeah,that's not the only issue,but this issue is the most serious

Comment: i put the `out.close();` part outside but still the same output like in image 2

Comment: @Phill i followed your instructions and it worked for me now. thank you

Answer (score 4):

Look at what you're writing to the output buffer and where.

Inside your `for` loop, you are writing a complete HTML document (ie `<html><body>...</body></html>`) and an entire table with header row and one data row.

What I assume you want to do is keep writing table rows to the one table. To do so, write the aforementioned tags **outside** your `for` loop

```
out.write("<html><body><table border=\"1\"><thead>" +
        "<tr><td>Station Number</td><td>Station Name</td>" +
        "<td>Status</td><td>As of Date</td></tr></thead><tbody>");
for(int station : stations) {
    // get data, determine rowcolor, etc
    out.write(rowcolor + ... + "</tr>");
}

out.write("</tbody></table></body></html>");
out.close();
```